# Complete list of possible policies in a sam template

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I'm trying to find a complete list of policies that can be added to the sam's template but I can't find any information either on amazon's official documentation nor by googling for it.

I'm in the process of converting a lambda application to sam and it requires a lot of polices so I need a list of what policies exist and what they are named. So what are the possible policies you can put on a sam application?

My template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
    AWS Serverless Application

    Sample SAM Template for AWS Serverless Application

Globals:
    Function:
        Timeout: 20
        Runtime: java8


Resources:
    example:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: target/aws-lambda.zip
            Handler: com.example.ExampleRequestHandler::handleRequest
            Events:
                example:
                    Type: Api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /example
                        Method: post
            Policies: # <- This field
                - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [all_aws_managed_policies.json](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/55b358748be3c314f956)

A list of all AWS managed policies and they're [sic] policy documents as well as a short script to generate the list.

> I [wrote] this code so that I could easily see the details of the managed policies since AWS doesn't publish them.